# Convert string to timestamp and split the data

Tags: python, string, jupyter-notebook, timestamp

I have a dataset like this:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'time':['13:30', '9:20', '18:12', '19:00', '8:20']})
```

I split the time to get the `hour` part only and add it to the table.

```py
data['hour'] = data.Time.apply(lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))
```

Now I want to split the time into 3 parts of the day and 3 meal times, assume the hour interval `(6,11]` is for breakfast, `(11,15]` for lunch, and `(15,20]` for dinner.

I tried this code but seems to not working.

```py
def time_period(hour):
    if hour >= 6 and hour < 11:
        return 'breakfast'
    elif hour >= 11 and hour < 15:
        return 'lunch'
    else:
        return 'dinner'
time = [time_period(y) for y in hours]
date['meal'] = time
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: So much typo in code

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think this code is incomplete.  What is `hours`, as used in `time = [time_period(y) for y in hours]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pandas.apply()`

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'time':['13:30', '9:20', '18:12', '19:00', '8:20']})
data['hour'] = data['time'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))

def time_period(hour):
    if hour >= 6 and hour < 11:
        return 'breakfast'
    elif hour >= 11 and hour < 15:
        return 'lunch'
    else:
        return 'dinner'

data['meal'] = data['hour'].apply(lambda x: time_period(x))
```

output

```
time    hour    meal
13:30   13  lunch
9:20    9   breakfast
18:12   18  dinner
19:00   19  dinner
8:20    8   breakfast
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html#pandas.IntervalIndex):

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'time':['13:30', '9:20', '18:12', '19:00', '8:20']})
>>> s = data.time.str.split(':', expand=True)[0].astype(int)
# Or, more appropriate in this case:
>>> s = pd.to_datetime(data.time, format='%H:%M').dt.hour
>>> ix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([6, 11, 15, 20], closed='right')
>>> mealtime = pd.Series(['breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner'], index=ix)
>>> df['meal'] = mealtime.loc[s].to_numpy()
>>> df

    time       meal
0  13:30      lunch
1   9:20  breakfast
2  18:12     dinner
3  19:00     dinner
4   8:20  breakfast
```

With chaining:

```
>>> data.assign(
        meal=pd.Series(
            ['breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner'], 
            index=pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([6, 11, 15, 20], closed='right')
        ).loc[pd.to_datetime(data.time, format='%H:%M').dt.hour].to_numpy()
    )

    time       meal
0  13:30      lunch
1   9:20  breakfast
2  18:12     dinner
3  19:00     dinner
4   8:20  breakfast
```